# How to change the anchor point for drawable when drawing on google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, anchor, drawable

In my android app, I have a map view and I draw an image on it. I followed this tutorial here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview.

But how do I change the anchor point (image origin) of the image being drawn? I think its currently using the center of the image or the top left, but since I'm using the Google marker image, I want the anchor to be the center bottom of the image.

Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Marker icons and images usually have an 'anchor' property which you can set, same as you set their size and image URL.  I've only done this with JavaScript though, not pure Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                                  .title("Marker in Sydney"))
                                  .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                                   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                   R.drawable.marker)));
```